# How to use math to create more efficient code?

Tags: c#

I'm horrible with Math, however I'm working diligently to change that. I hate writing ugly, inefficient code. I'm currently developing a small hobby game and I need to be able to calculate adjacent tiles. I decided against using x,y coords and instead each tile has a unique id. I have the following functional code, however I'm struggling to find a way to make it not so ugly:

```
this.AdjacentTiles = new int[8];
this.AdjacentTiles[0] = (id - 9) - 1;
this.AdjacentTiles[1] = (id - 9);
this.AdjacentTiles[2] = (id - 9) + 1;
this.AdjacentTiles[3] = (id - 1);
this.AdjacentTiles[4] = (id + 1);
this.AdjacentTiles[5] = (id + 9) - 1;
this.AdjacentTiles[6] = (id + 9);
this.AdjacentTiles[7] = (id + 9) + 1;
```

I know it's possible to calculate all this within a single, tidy for loop, however I just can't wrap my head around how to do so. I don't necessarily want to be spoon fed, because like I said I'm trying to improve myself, I just need some direction.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the significance of the expressions like `(id - 9) - 1`?  I would have expected to see some `x, y` expressions.  And maybe an enum like: `enum AdjacentName { N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW }`.  And maybe a function that does the work for me (I give the function a pair of coordinates and a direction and it gives me the new coordinates (or an indication that I've hit an edge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *math* is relatively easy, with something like (pseudo-code):

```
index = 0
for row = -1 to 1 inclusive:                    # prev/this/next row
    for col = -1 to 1 inclusive:                # prev/this/next col
        if row != 0 or col != 0:                # ignore current cell
            array[index++] = id + row * 3 + col
```

That will set the elements to what you need. However, you *may* want to consider the edge cases such as when `id` is in the left-most column. In that case, there are *no* adjacent cells to the left, unless you've created an array with empty edges.

Comment: Thank you. This helped more than you know.